# Add folder to Windows 10 Library programmatically in a batch file or PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, batch-file, user-folders

How do I add a folder to a Library (such as Documents, Music, Videos, Pictures) in Windows 10 programmatically using either a batch file command or PowerShell (or indeed a PowerShell command within a batch file)?

I found a tool called [shlib.exe (Shell Library)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120828-01/?p=6743) that comes with Windows 7 SDK that can do this, but I can't find anything for Windows 10. I also found a programmatic method [online](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-working-with-windows-libraries/) that uses Windows Shell API, but this applies to Windows 7, not Windows 10:

```
$doc = [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellLibrary]::Load('Music', $false)
$doc.Add('C:\Share\Music')
```

Any help to achieve this would be appreciated as there currently seems to be no easy way in Windows 10 (perhaps Microsoft have deliberately locked it down so it can only now be done within File Explorer itself).

Answer (score -1):

Use the Powershell [New-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

```
New-Item -Path C:\Users\SomeUser\Music\Newfolder -ItemType Directory
```

Comment: This only creates a new directory. It doesn't _add_ a directory to a Library.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this in PowerShell is possible, but quite complex.
Coming from bash world, my excursion into PowerShell scripting showed the limitations of this language, in particular the messy handling of return values and xml data.
Here is some PowerShell script adding folders containing specific file patterns to a library (with lots of debugging output).

https://gist.github.com/uvwild76f0047af33d79504ca14dd85e1a2f90

Comment: [link-only answers are not accepted on stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/230282) because they can rot at any time, or not accessible like in this case, rendering the question/answer invalid