# Add a file or a folder to Windows 10 Library programmatically in PowerShell or in a Cli program?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

For example adding a folder to one of the default libraries, Documents. Either through PowerShell or a CMD command. I came across this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1482199/add-folder-to-windows-10-library-programmatically-in-a-batch-file-or-powershell) but its 2 years old and the one answer for it is wrong.

Comment: try this `https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-working-with-windows-libraries/`. You will need to `Find-Package` and `Install-Package` first though, the link does not work anymore

Comment: @SimonS so close! thats exactly what I need. Do you think there are alternative links are site that I can those two required file? Thanks allot for that.

Comment: Clickable: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-working-with-windows-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

A kind user from another forum pointed me to this article and I am gonna share it here and in turn answer my own question as there is not much information on this subject as it is.

Here is the article [here](https://www.grimadmin.com/article.php/creating-modifying-windows-7-libraries). It goes into alot more detail about how Windows manages libraries and how it stores its setting files.

The examples use a tool called `SLUtil.exe` commands (Linked in the article)

**Create "Recipes" Library:**

```
slutil create Recipes
```

**Add Folder to Library:**

```
slutil addfolder Recipes "C:\Demo\Baking Recipes"
```

**Delete Folder from Library:**

```
slutil removefolder Recipes "C:\Demo\Baking Recipes"
```

**Set Default Save Location:**

```
slutil savefolder Recipes "C:\Demo\Pastry Recipes"
```